# Remove Price Based On Yes/No Attribute

Tags: magento2.3, price, if

I have created an attribute 'priceless' and I have successfully removed the add to cart button based on whether it is set to 'yes' or 'no'.

I wish to do the same for the price field. **If attribute 'priceless' is 'yes' then don't show price.**

Can anyone please help with the file I would update to get this functionality working?

Here's the code that worked to check the setting in the `addtocart.phtml` `<?php if($_product->getPriceless()): ?>` is there an equivalent phtml file for price?